# Problem with Docker display and apps with Qt Platform in ROS

Tags: docker, qt5, ros, wsl-2

I am using Docker on Windows with WSL Ubuntu 22.04.6 LTS. Also, I am using the ROS Noetic Image in Docker.

When I use 'sudo apt-get install rviz' all is correct, I can install it. But when I try to use 'rosrun rviz rviz' I receive this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwDTt.png)

It occurs when I try to use any QT app. What could be the problem?

I've seen several issues with this same error, but none of the possible solutions have been satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try X server for windows? like VcXsrv
You can try export display variable in WSl with

> export DISPLAY=:0

if you use X other steps here:

1. configure x server to allow connections
2. disable access control on the x server(sometimes, x server may block connnections from docker containers)
3. make sure the docker image has support for gui apps (some ros images are cli only)
4. install packages "x11-apps" "x11-server-utils" "dbus" (you can check these packages)
5. verify docker run parameters

> docker run -it --env="DISPLAY" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" ros:noetic

and check for SELinux or AppArmor

Comment: if  export DISPLAY=:0 does not work you can try with ip of your host like
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0

Comment: Hello! I've already tried 'export DISPLAY' several times, but I'm still unsuccessful. As for setting up X server, I don't have much of a clue since I'm a beginner in this. What steps could I take to set this up correctly?

Comment: Now I'm testing with Virtual Box inside an Ubuntu 20.04 image and with ros noetic, I'm getting the same error from Display and GUI apps